# Bonfire - Authenticated_controller - Fatal error: Call to a member function is_ajax_request() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, bonfire

I am trying to setup an area that is accessible only for the registered users, using Bonfire/CodeIgniter. Per Bonfire documentation, we can use the Authenticated_controller. When I try to extend my controller from Authenticated_controller, I get the error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function is_ajax_request() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\bonfire\bonfire\libraries\template.php on line 264

The code that I have is for the controller boffice:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * boffice controller
 */
class Boffice extends Authenticated_Controller
{
    public $ci;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->lang->load('boffice');

    $this->load->model('pan/pan_model', null, true);
    $this->load->model('activities/activity_model');                

    Assets::add_module_js('boffice', 'boffice.js');
    Template::set_theme("jumbotron");
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------


/**
 * Displays a list of form data.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function index()
{

    Template::render();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------



}
```

Other Warnings that I get are listed below:

> ERROR - 2014-08-15 13:10:19 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\xampp\htdocs\bonfire\bonfire\libraries\template.php 258
>   ERROR - 2014-08-15 13:10:19 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\xampp\htdocs\bonfire\bonfire\libraries\template.php 258
>   ERROR - 2014-08-15 13:10:19 --> Severity: Notice  --> Trying to get property of non-object D:\xampp\htdocs\bonfire\bonfire\libraries\template.php 264

The code in template.php where the error occurs:

```
255     public static function render($layout=NULL)
256 {
257     $output = '';
258     $controller = self::$ci->router->class;
259
260     // We need to know which layout to render
261     $layout = empty($layout) ? self::$layout : $layout;
262
263     // Is it in an AJAX call? If so, override the layout
264     if (self::$ci->input->is_ajax_request())
265     {
267         $layout = self::$ci->config->item('template.ajax_layout');
268
269         $controller = NULL;
270     }
```

I have seen similar error messages and the problem has been not having an object initialized. This one "is_ajax_request()" type error is nowhere to be found and I am not sure how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you copy this line `D:\xampp\htdocs\bonfire\bonfire\libraries\template.php 264` here ?

Comment: Edited the post to include the lines from template.php 258-270, where the error occrus. @MRSrinivas